# Installing RAID card, does it matter which of the two ports I use first?

Tags: raid, sas

I am installing a HP P410 RRAID controller onto a HP Proliant DL320 G6. The card has two SAS ports, but I only need one. Does it matter which of the two ports I use? There is no indication on the card itself. I don't know if RAID cards work like RAM, where you're supposed to use certain ports/slots first..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port will not have an impact.  You can use either.

Comment: Thanks, I know its a basic question, but I'd rather be safe then sorry.

Comment: Basic questions are often the ones that trip people up / put them off doing things. That's why its great to have a definitive answer